# passing data attribute to rails link_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, turbolinks

Trying to disable turbolinks in a `link_to` block

Here's what I have now, and does what I need it too except for disable turbolinks.

```
<%= link_to posts_path do %>   
    <li class="nav-icon nav-icon-home">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" data-icon="&#x25a8;"></span>
            <span class="nav-icon-text">Home</span>
    </li> 
<% end %>
```

Now, to use the above and disable turbolinks I'd like to do something like this...

```
<%= link_to posts_path, :data => { :no_turbolink => true }do %>   
    ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Give a space between `{ :no_turbolink => true }` and `do`:

```
<%= link_to posts_path, :data => { :no_turbolink => true } do %>   
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: To use latest Ruby syntax, `{ no_turbolink: true }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to posts_path , :data => { :no_turbolink => true } do %>   
 <li class="nav-icon nav-icon-home">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" data-icon="&#x25a8;">      </span>
        <span class="nav-icon-text">Home</span>
</li> 
<% end %>
```